# Instantiate inline Component without Loader

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Is there a way of instantiating an inline `Component` (i.e. defined in the same file) without using a `Loader`? I'm less concerned about the performance impact of using `Loader`s as I am about polluting my file with lots of `Loader` wrappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Repeater` to create components without `Loader`.
Or you can even use `Qt.createComponent` to do that.

Take a look at Qt Documentation about [Dynamic Component Creation in QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html)

information and examples about `Repeater` can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html)

You can even create component from string on the fly:

```
Rectangle {
    id: appWindow
    width: 300; height: 300

    Component.onCompleted: {
      var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0; Rectangle {color: "red"; width: 20; height: 20}',
                                       appWindow,
                                       "dynamicSnippet1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I find that the [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) page can be misleading.

There's no mention about using a declaratively created [`Component`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) or using models instead. It mentions only `Qt.createComponent` or `Qt.createQmlObject` which are needlessly imperative (and relying on strings) most of the time.

I would advise using an inline [`Component`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) with [`createObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method) instead for more readable and maintainable code. Like so :

```
Rectangle {
    id: appWindow
    width: 300; height: 300

    Component {
        id: redRectComponent
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            width: 20
            height: 20
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var newObject = redRectComponent.createObject(appWindow);
    }
}
```

I'd use this method if I wanted to create a temporary object imperatively, like a popup for example.

If I were to create several of those objects, I'd most likely use a  `ListModel` with a `ListView`/`Repeater`/`Instantiator`/... like so:

```
ListModel {
    id: rectModel
}

Column {
    Repeater {
        model: rectModel
        Rectangle {
            color: model.rectColor
            width: 20
            height: 20
        }
    }
}

Button {
    onClicked: rectModel.append({rectColor: "red"})
}
```

Here I don't even have to handle the the object creation, I just insert some data in the `ListModel` and the `Repeater` takes care of the instantiation of the delegates.