# Inline/same file object type definition

Tags: qt, qml

I can define object type like so:

```
// Test.qml
import QtQuick 2.6

Rectangle {
    width: 50
    height: 50
}
```

and easily reuse with set properties like color

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Test {
        color: "blue"
    }

    Test {
        x:50
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

But sometimes I have object that I would like to reuse only in a single file. So creating additional file for object that I would only reuse in that single file doesn't seem right.

Can Something similar shown in the example above be done in the same file?

Comment: use [Component](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Something similar shown in the example above be done in the same file?

This question seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855962/qml-instantiate-inline-component-without-loader) one. You can use [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) or [dynamic object creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html), but I don't think that's better than moving the code to a separate file, as you've done in your example.

> So creating additional file for object that I would only reuse in that single file doesn't seem right.

I disagree with this. It's still a benefit to reuse a component even if the reuse occurs in a single file. It's much clearer to read code that directly instantiates component instances rather than using loaders or dynamic object creation.